# Broaden the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made one graph. but, the x axis's text is overlapped. This is my graph and code.

[image]

```
    library("ggplot2")

    fx_rates <- read.csv(file="NRUSD2.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")

    fx_rates = fx_rates[,1:5]

    head(fx_rates)

    library(reshape)
    mdata <- melt(fx_rates, id=c("time"))


    head(mdata)

    library(scales)


    p1 <- ggplot(mdata, aes(x=time, y=value, colour=factor(variable), group=variable)) +
          geom_line() +
          ggtitle("Global Fx rate")

    p1 +  theme_bw()
    p1
```

In this graph, the time text is overlapped. so I changed the rectangle as 90.

```
p1 <- ggplot(mdata, aes(x=time, y=value, colour=factor(variable), group=variable)) +
      geom_line() +
      ggtitle("Global Fx rate")+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                                       size=8, angle=90))
```

but I want to broad x axis. Many people said " Use scale_x_continuous". but I don't know how to use....

you can download csv file in this link.
http://blog.naver.com/tjdudwo93/220842781714

Comment: Did u mean the x-axis labels? I would suggest you to change its angle to 45 degree or so instead of broadening the x-axis if that's okay for you.

Comment: Did u try scale_x_continous( limits = c( xmin, xmax))?

Comment: Your time variable is of class factor or character. Make it Date or POSIXct and the axis problem is solved.

Comment: Roland! can i get your solution code?

Comment: user3801801! when i use your code. "object 'xmin' not found"<<this error message happen. the xaxis value is year-month. so can you give me a value of xmin&xmax?

Comment: See `help("as.POSIXct")`